# Get notified when mouse is over a particular NSMenuItem

Tags: cocoa, notifications, highlight, nsnotificationcenter, nsmenuitem

Is there a way to be notified when mouse enters and exit from a particular `NSMenuItem` without using a custom NSView?

I tried subclassing NSMenuItem and overriding `-(BOOL)isHighlighted` but it doesn't seem to work.

Have you got any hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you try setting a menu delegate and receiving the `menu:willHighlightItem:` delegate call?